# Referencing a constructor from a different js file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

```
//default.js
const item = require("./item.js");
var itemTest = new item.ItemTest("weapon",1,1,1);
console.log(itemTest.name);

//item.js

module.exports = class ItemTest {
    constructor(name, value, attack, defense) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
    }

}
```

I've also tried it with simply

```
 //item.js
    function ItemTest(name, value, attack, defense) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
    }
```

but that also returns "item.ItemTest is not a constructor". if that function is added into default.js then it works just fine, but I don't know how to make it pull the constructor object from the other file.

Comment: With regard to your first try, change it to `var itemTest = new item("weapon",1,1,1);` (You're exporting the `class`, so in default.js, `item` is the class; just imagine whatever you're setting to `module.exports` is what replaces `require()`)

Comment: Whatever you assign to `module.exports` IS what you get when you do `require()` of that module.  So when you do `const Item = require('./item.js');`, then `Item` is your `class` that you exported so you'd just do `new Item()`.

Answer (score 1):

I made few changes to your existing code by replacing these lines `const item = require("./item.js");` and `var itemTest = new item.ItemTest("weapon",1,1,1);` with these `const ItemTest = require("./item");` and `var itemTest = new ItemTest("weapon", 1, 1, 1);`

```
//default.js
const ItemTest = require("./item");
var itemTest = new ItemTest("weapon", 1, 1, 1);
console.log(itemTest.name);

//item.js
class ItemTest {
    constructor(name, value, attack, defense) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
    }

}

module.exports = ItemTest;
```

In the code above, I am exporting `ItemTest` so you have access to it when you use `require()`. On requiring the file, you get the class exported.

Comment: This is correct, but please also explain what you changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

In Item.js you need to change

```js
class ItemTest {
    constructor(name, value, attack, defense) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
    }

}

class MyClass {}

// If you want to export more stuff, do
module.exports = {ItemTest: ItemTest, MyClass: MyClass};


// But if you have only ItemTest, then you can do
module.exports = ItemTest;

// This will change the main code to be like 
var ItemTest = require('./item');
var itemTest = new ItemTest();
```

Comment: mind explaining what module.exports = {ItemTest: ItemTest}; does? What's the first and the second ItemTest specificailly doing?

Comment: It will export json object with key ItemTest and its value is the class ItemTest. This needed since you are calling item.ItemTest after importing the file which require item to have json key ItemTest.

Comment: Much better: `exports.ItemTest = ItemTest;`.

Comment: The "much better" is `exports = ItemTest;` and `var ItemTest  = require('./item.js');` but I did export `{ItemTest}` in case he wants to export more stuff within the same file :)